# Not safe typescript compilation when webpack-dev-server npm package is installed

Tags: typescript, webpack-dev-server, typescript-typings

I have a very small project written in typescript and it is currently compiled with Babel. I want to get rid of Babel and leave just a typescript compiler to produce the result JS. Also, I want to have JS working on mobile and old desktop browsers, so I leave a default target setting - 'ECMA Script 3'.

To demonstrate my issue, it's enough to complie a script with one line of code:

```
let clone = Object.assign({}, {a:1});
```

Initially, compiler successfully catches the issue and shows an error:

```
test.ts:1:20 - error TS2339: Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.
```

But as soon as I install ;webpack-dev-server' npm package, compiler stops seeing this problem and completes the compilation with no errors.

My little research showed that the problem is caused by '@types/node' package in my node_modules as it brings references to es2018.

In node_modules>@types>node>ts3.2>index.d.ts I see:

```
/// <reference lib="es2018" />
```

Apparently, Object.assign is a valid method for ES2018 and that's why compiler stops complaining.

The reason I have this package installed as it is a transitive dependency on the following path:

```
webpack-dev-server -> del -> @types/glob -> @types/node
```

It leaves me with a question if it is possible to have 'webpack-dev-server' npm added to my project and have ts compiler catching 'Object.assing' problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually configure `types` property in your `tsconfig.json` file.

In it's simplest form:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es3",
        "types": []
    }
}
```

See [`@types`, `typeRoots` and `types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) for more details.