# Safe typescript compilation when polyfills are used

Tags: typescript, core-js

Let's say I have a project with two typescript files:

- a.ts
- b.ts.

My *tsconfig.json*:

```
{
    "target": "ES5",            // old browser support is required
    "lib": ["dom", "es5"],      // 
    "types": []                 // 
}
```

I left *types* setting empty as I don't want to pickup typings from any third party packages (e.g. *@types/node* typings installed as a dependency of webpack-dev-server package; details are [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643929/not-safe-typescript-compilation-when-webpack-dev-server-npm-package-is-installed))

Now I decided to use some new JS feature and added the following line to *a.ts* file:

```
let clone = Object.assign({}, {a:1});
```

Luckily, compiler is smart enough to warn me with the following warning:

```
a.ts:1:20 - error TS2339: Property 'assign' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.
```

So I have to add a polyfill (e.g. [CORE-JS package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js)) and add an import statement to *a.ts*:

```
import 'core-js/modules/es.object.assign'
let clone = Object.assign({}, {a:1});
```

But typescript compiler is still not happy, as it doesn't have *typings* for my newly polyfilled *assign* method . I tried to install [@types/core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/core-js) package and add its name to my tsconfig.json file, but it didn't work so I created my own type definition file *object.d.ts*:

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    assign(target: any, ...sources: any[]): any;
}
```

Everything started to work. Hooray!

Then, I added another new feature, but this time in *b.ts* file.

```
import 'core-js/modules/es.array.from'
console.log(Array.from('foo'));
```

And I also added a type definition for a new method (file array.d.ts):

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
    from<T>(arrayLike: ArrayLike<T>): T[];
}
```

And now, as both my typing files are globally accessible, I can use *Array.from* in *a.ts*, and *Object.assign* in *b.ts* and that's a problem. Unless I add

```
import 'core-js/modules/es.object.assign'
```

to *b.ts*, the code won't work in old browsers and compiler won't tell me about it.

So, here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to use type definitions from @types/core-js and expose types one by one (as I'm adding polyfills for them)?
2. Is it possible to make my own type definitions visible to a particular files (not globally visible), so I'll have control over what is polyfilled in each file?

PS: I will not bundle my two files, as they have to be delivered separately. Extracting polyfill imports into a separate modules and later add imports to that module in each file is not a desired option for me, as it will potentially create references to polyfills which are not used in my files and I want to keep result files as small as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular form of import statement which you are using

```
import 'core-js/modules/es.object.assign'
```

is called ["import for side-effects only"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127479/es6-import-for-side-effects-meaning), for a reason. This statement does not have any effect on module scope where the import appears, the effect, if present, is global and is not obvious unless you examine what the code in the imported module actually does.

These [particular](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.array.from.js#L11) [polyfills](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/modules/es.object.assign.js#L6) add [static methods](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/export.js#L31) to [global](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/packages/core-js/internals/global.js) `Object` and `Array` constructors.

So your type definitions for those polyfills seem to work properly, at least if `a.js` and `b.js` are going to be run in the same execution context and share the same global objects.

Then, it does not matter in which module you import the polyfill, it will modify shared global objects which are available in all modules, with one exception - when you have statements in the module scope (not inside any function) which are executed immediately when the module is loaded. For those statements, the availablility of polyfills depends on module loading order, but anything that depends on module loading order should be avoided if at all possible.

> Is it possible to make my own type definitions visible to a particular files (not globally visible), so I'll have control over what is polyfilled in each file?

This is only necessary if each file is going to be executed in its own execution context, for example one file is in a web page and another file is in the service worker code. Then code in each file actually refers to different global objects, but TypeScript does not have an adequate way to represent that when the files are compiled together - at compile time (for type declarations), there's only one global scope. In this case, you have to compile each file in its own separate project with separate `tsconfig.json` files, and include typings for `Array.from` and `Object.assign` only where they are needed.

Comment: Artem, my scripts will be executed in separate execution contexts, and I also thought about having 2 separate tsconfig.json files + webpack.config. I was afraid to hear confirmation of that idea as it seemed to me little bit hard to setup and maintain later on. If nobody else comes up with a better alternative, I will accept your answer. Thanks for your answer.